# Associativity of addition

Tags: arithmetic, integers, associativity

This question is about addition of positive integers with more than one digit, a topic covered in second grade. But it's not really elementary.

But first we need to introduce the positive integers $\mathbb N$ the way a second grader conceives them. Of course they will not think of $\mathbb N$ as the set defined by the Peano axioms. Instead, we start with the 10 symbols $A=\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ and we $\bf define$ a positive integer to be a finite string $a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_1a_0$ where each $a_i\in A$ (and they are not all zero). Then we define the operation of addition by the usual algorithm involving carries that is taught in second grade. Here is my question: prove that this operation is associative. Disclaimer: I know how to prove it, but surely my proof could  not be explained to a second grader. I would like to know if there is a really elementary proof.

Comment: Instead of base $10$, you could use base $1$, the unary numeral system, where $5$ is represented by $11111$. That's nearer to Peano axioms than base $10$ is, and associativity can be visually proven easily. Although that would not be a formal proof, it is sufficient for second graders. Then associativity is proven for base $10$ too, because it does not depend upon the chosen encoding of numbers. And proving that a base $1$ number can be encoded is base $10$ is less difficult than associativity in base $10$.

Answer (score 4):

The addition algorithm involving carries should be a theorem, not a definition, even for a 2nd grader. Addition should be defined semantically, and the obvious way to do it at the 2nd grade level makes associativity obvious: if Alice, Bob, and Carol have $a, b, c$ apples, and they pool their apples together, they have $a + b + c$ apples.

I write this without parentheses because this operation does not involve any parentheses: "pool their apples together" is an $n$-ary operation that immediately makes sense without any reference to a binary operation. Other intuitive forms of counting and addition could be used here: for example, Alice, Bob, and Carol might be carrying three sticks of lengths $a, b, c$, and then I'd tell you to line those sticks up to produce a bigger stick of length $a + b + c$ (note that this makes commutativity a little less obvious). Or Alice, Bob, and Carol might be carrying three rocks of weight $a, b, c$, etc.

Then it is, again, a *theorem* that this operation reduces to binary addition, and that either parenthesization works. Alice, Bob, and Carol can pool their apples together either by having Alice and Bob pool their apples together first, then Carol, or by having Bob and Carol pool their apples together first, then Alice. This gives

$$a + b + c = (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$$

as desired. The point of presenting the argument this way is that $(a + b) + c$ and $a + (b + c)$ are equal because they are equal to a *third* operation, which is "add three things." Other associativity arguments in mathematics can be written to work exactly the same way (e.g. associativity of the tensor product).

Comment: A simple way to go about proving the theorem would be kind of "extra packaging" where candies are 1 each, bags are 10, boxes are 100, crates are 1000, and warehouses are 10000.

Comment: @mathlander: yes, but you implicitly apply commutativity and associativity many times when you argue that you can separate the sum out into the sums of the $10$s, then the $100$s, etc. So this argument doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I do not dispute the fact that the addition algorithm should be a theorem, but my question remains valid: IF we define addition that way, is there an elementary proof of associativity? My question is not entirely idle either. In many introductions to p-adic analysis, that is exactly how p-adic numbers and the operation of addition are defined, and it is then stated without proof that such operation is associative. But I did not find it so easy to prove. This made me realize that associativity of ordinary addition as taught in second grade is likewise not easy to prove.

Comment: @Math101: for $p$-adic numbers this can also be completely avoided by giving a different definition that is obviously associative. You define the $p$-adic numbers to be the cofiltered limit of the quotients $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$; this embeds the $p$-adic numbers as a subring of $\prod_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{Z}/p^n$ and then commutativity and associativity of both addition and multiplication follow directly from commutativity and associativity of those operations in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$, which in turn follows directly from commutativity and associativity of addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I take your point that you are asking for a "direct" proof that adding-with-carries is associative. Probably such a thing can be done but it sounds tedious. Much better to just prove that addition *means* something and that what it *means* is obviously associative (which I would argue is what the cofiltered limit argument for the $p$-adic numbers does). Digits are useful for some purposes but not others, and proving associativity is a situation where they're not useful. (And, again: proving that $p$-adic numbers have digits and can be added by carrying should be a *theorem*.)

Answer (score 1):

(Extending my comment into an answer)

I would like to argue that the difficulty lies in *the way integers are defined*, not in associativity by itself.

Young children conceive integers first as a property of real life objects: their cardinal. They learn to count by enumerating objects; and **enumeration** is the essence of $\mathbb{N}$.

In math language we call "property" an equivalence class, and we formalize enumeration by various means, e.g. the successor function used in Peano axioms.

Children have an immediate understanding of enumeration, and of the sequence of integers. They do not have an immediate understanding of base-$10$ encoding. That comes soon, because the name of integers reflects this encoding after some language-dependent limit (typically $10$ or $16$ or $20$). But enumeration comes first.

Actually, the very fact that we write math sentences on a sheet of paper has a prerequisite: the sheet of paper enables to put symbols one after the other, as many as we want. So enumeration comes even *before* axioms. This is also true when using a proof assistant such as Coq or Agda or Lean: one relies on a virtually infinite enumeration of memory cells. And this is also true of the infinite sequence of cells in the Turing machine.

So which encoding of integers reflects the most this intuitive concept of enumeration? **Unary encoding**, the [unary numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system). Which is: an integer is encoded into as many $1$'s; $5$ is encoded as $11111$.
This is what we use when counting things one by one; I remember doing that in a vote place, before we got voting machines. We count with sticks.

This uses the definition of integers as cardinal of objects sets. And the good thing is: in this encoding, addition is obvious (that's just appending two sets of $1$'s), as well as commutativity and associativity.

(By the way, I learned to use unary encoding in complexity theory; this is explained in the Wikipedia page).
A drawback of unary encoding is that zero cannot be represented without a separate symbol (unless using blank space to represent an empty set of $1$'s, which is akward).

There is a well-known argument that groups are so important in maths and physics because they represent *actions*, and actions in real life are associative and have a neutral element (i.e. doing nothing). By having a very limited kind of actions (appending sequences of $1$'s) we rely on that.

On the other hand, base-$10$ encoding is difficult to use, for the reasons you mention: addition is a nightmare to define and to prove its properties.

There are other drawbacks to using base-$10$ encoding as a definition of integers:

- That gives too much importance to one encoding among many; i.e. one can use other bases, notably base-$2$.
- There are other encodings which do not follow this principle of making packets of $N$, $N^2$, $N^3$ etc. objects.
- "Why can't I put a leading zero?" is a frequent question; with unary encoding this question does not exist.
- This problem repeats itself when defining real numbers. The layman definition of a real number is an integer followed by a comma followed by a finite or infinite sequence of digits. Which poses the same problem of defining addition and multiplication and their properties, plus the non-uniqueness of encoding.

So **the easiest way to define integers** with addition and its properties for second graders, in my opinion, is to:

- Define integers as a property of objects sets - putting objects visually in bijection, i.e. saying their number is the same if you can make pairs of objects and there is none left in either set.
- Defining addition as grouping two sets together.
- Showing visually that this is obviously commutative and associative.
- Showing unary encoding as an example of such sets.
- *Then* defining base-$10$ encoding.
- Showing (if you feel this is necessary) that each base-$10$ encoded number has a unique unary encoded representant, and the other way round.
- Deriving addition for base-$10$ encoding from addition of sets of $1$'s. Then addition properties that have already been proven in unary encoding are transferred into base-$10$ encoding (which actually uses an intuitive property of bijections).

The last two steps are the most difficult ones, but I believe they are less difficult, and more intuitive, than doing all the work with base-$10$ encoding from the beginning.

All that being said, perhaps you just have to define integers by their base-$10$ encoding because that is officially prescribed in the place where you teach.

Comment: The unary representation is an interesting way to address the problem. I have now become convinced that there really isn't an easy way to prove associativity if we define integers by their decimal expansion, and either one disentangles the carry function for the sum $a+b+c$ in all its gory details (and it can be done), or one has to rely on a different definition of integers and then prove the decimal expansion.

Comment: But my original question originated exactly from the fact that often p-adic numbers are defined as strings of digits, then addition defined using the carry function, and then  it is stated without any proof that the operation is associative. See this paper (on page 2) as an example, but there are more. http://www.madore.org/~david/math/padics.pdf

Comment: To address your last comment, no, I do not have to teach integers that way, my question originated by reading papers on p-adic analysis that define integers as strings of digits.

Comment: @Math101 Indeed the paper on $p$-adic numbers you quote has a tedious explanation on how to perform addition and multiplication on $p$-adic integers, without formally proving some properties such as associativity, and only dealing with integers. In fact I prefer $p$-adic numbers built using the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the metric defined by $p$-adic absolute value.